# invalid character in identifier for inputting values and getting an equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the equation of circle in Python. I am running the code below using package cmath. I am getting the error that there is an invalid character in the equation

```
y = k + cmath.sqrt(r − (x−h)k)
                     ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

```
import cmath

print('Solve the circle equation: y= sqrt(- h*x - k*y - r - x**2)')
r = float(input('Please enter r : '))
h = float(input('Please enter h : '))
k = float(input('Please enter k : '))

y = k + cmath.sqrt(r − (x−h)k)
print('The circle equation is "y = k + cmath.sqrt(r − (x−h)k)"'.format(y))
```

Comment: ...did you just fix the code in the question?

Comment: Please stop changing the question.

Comment: If it's a different issue, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the `*` operator if you mean to multiply `(x-h)` by `k`:

```
y = k + cmath.sqrt(r − (x−h) * k)
```